# Numerically calculating inverse Laplace via the inverse Laplace transformation formula

Tags: numerical-methods, integration, complex-numbers, laplace-transform, control-theory

I'm trying to simulate a control system whose transfer function is $H(s)$. I'm comparing different numerical methods for this. I have already used these two methods:
- Converting the transfer function to the state space form, then iterating then system.
- Converting the transfer function into the discrete form by bilinear transformation, then solving the difference equation.

Next, I want to do the simulation by directly solving the inverse Laplace transformation formula:

$
\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{H(s)\} = f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}e^{st}H(s)\,ds, \quad \mbox{(where } \quad \sigma = Re\{s\} \mbox{)}
$

The problem is that I don't know about complex integration. A typical transfer function I'm dealing with is $H(s) = \frac{1}{s+4}$. For this transfer function, what values of $\sigma$ and $T$ should I choose? Assuming that the system will always be real, should the integration return a real number (absolute value of the result), or a complex number?

I'm going to use C++ language for the implementation, and use rectangular rule to solve the integral. What must be the maximum step size of the integration for not seeing any error by eye when I look at the plotting of the output signal?

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma$ has to be chosen such that it is greater than the real part of all singularities of $H$, in your case greater than $-4$. $T$ should just be large enough (your $H$ has an obvious decay for $\Im(s) \to \infty$, you could try to work out estimates on the error for the truncation of the integral).

But why do you want to solve the integral numerically (since the inverse transform in known explicitly, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms)? If its just for comparison, then the question boils down to how to calculate improper integral numerically.

Comment: The transfer function I wrote is just a simple example to start with. I'm going to work with more complicated ones (whose time domain expressions will not be easily found from that table) once I manage to implement this algorithm.